# How to make class variables persist between modules in VBA

Tags: vba, class

I am trying to find a way for class variables to persist between modules.
I have a use class that stores typical user data: Name, domain, manager, etc.

I'd like to store this information throughout the life of the session (while the user is using the tool), but it looks like I can't do that. Below is an example and thank for your help/advice!
JP

Here is the class module:

```
Private cLoggedDomain As String
Private cLoggedRole As String
Private cDepartment As String
Private cEmployeeName As String
Private cManagerName As String
Private cEmp_ID As Long
Private cEmployeeInfo As Collection

Public Property Let SetUser(value As String)
    'RECIEVES THE LOGGED DOMAIN AS STRING
    'GETS THE DB ATTRIBUTES FROM SQL
    Set cEmployeeInfo = GetInfoFromSearch("Employee, manager, department, ety_type, emp_ID", _
                                         "domainID = '" & value & "'", _
                                         "Employee", "v_roster_empViewALL")

    cLoggedDomain = value
    cEmployeeName = cEmployeeInfo(1)(1)
    cManagerName = cEmployeeInfo(1)(2)
    cDepartment = cEmployeeInfo(1)(3)
    cLoggedRole = cEmployeeInfo(1)(4)
    cEmp_ID = cEmployeeInfo(1)(5)
End Property

Public Property Get LoggedDomain() As String
    LoggedDomain = cLoggedDomain
End Property

Public Property Let LoggedDomain(value As String)
    cLoggedDomain = value
End Property

Public Property Get LoggedRole() As String
    LoggedRole = cLoggedRole
End Property

Public Property Get LoggedDepartment() As String
    LoggedDepartment = cDepartment
End Property

Public Property Get LoggedEmployeeName() As String
    LoggedEmployeeName = cEmployeeName
End Property

Public Property Get LoggedManagerName() As String
    LoggedManagerName = cManagerName
End Property

Public Property Get LoggedEmpId() As String
    LoggedEmpId = cEmp_ID
End Property
```

And the module that uses it, which works fine:

```
Public Sub New_LoadMain()
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim loggedUser As New cRoles

    'CHECK TO SEE IF USER IS LOGGED IN
    If loggedUser.LoggedDomain = "" Then
        'Set loggedUser = New cRoles
         loggedUser.SetUser = Environ("username")

    Else

    End If

    Call test
```

However, when I try to use the test module, I get a with block error?

```
Sub test()
Dim test As cRoles
Dim t As String

t = test.LoggedDepartment

End Sub
```

Comment: In the `test` method you haven't set `test` (try not to use the same name as your method...) to an instance of `cRoles` - when you try to access it it's still `Nothing`

Comment: Side note, that `SetUser` property should probably be a method (`Sub`). Write-only properties are a design smell in OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class modules define the public interface for objects: they are *blueprints* that mean nothing until they are *instantiated* with the `New` keyword.

When you do this:

```
Dim test As cRoles
```

You allocate memory for an object pointer, and telling the compiler that this object implements the `cRoles` interface; that's how you can type `test.` and get a list of all the public members on that interface.

However that object pointer points to no object: it's `Nothing` (literally). You need to create a new instance of that class in order to access the object `test` is pointing to:

```
Set test = New cRoles
```

And now accessing `test` members will no longer throw error 91.

Now, each instance encapsulates its own state: think of each worksheet in your workbook as a `Worksheet` instance: each sheet has its own separate content, but all sheets can be manipulated through the same `Worksheet` interface, regardless of whether you're looking at `Sheet1` or `Sheet42`.

The same is true for all instances of your `cRoles` class:

```
Dim test1 As cRoles
Set test1 = New cRoles
test1.SetUser = user1

Dim test2 As cRoles
Set test2 = New cRoles
test2.SetUser = user2

Debug.Print test1.LoggedEmpId, test2.LoggedEmpId
```

The two instances are completely distinct, and each hold their own internal state. If that's what you want, then in order to create an instance in one place and consume it in another place, you'll need to pass the object reference as a parameter:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim thing As cRoles
    Set thing = New cRoles
    thing.SetUser = Environ("username")
    DoSomething thing
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething(ByVal auth As cRoles)
    Debug.Print auth.LoggedEmpId
End Sub
```

Note:

- You typically want to pass parameters `ByVal`
- Avoid `As New` since that makes an auto-instantiated object, and that comes with behavior that may or may not be expected.
- You could have a global-scope `Public AuthInfo As cRoles` variable declared in a standard module, then a procedure responsible for creating the object and setting this global-scope reference. Then you can access `AuthInfo` everywhere in your VBA project - the caveat being, that global variable can now be *written to* by any code in your VBA project. Prefer using local variables and parameters if possible.

Comment: This is a great overview of classes, thank you. Setting the global variable accomplished what I wanted! thanks again.